# How to check if bot is connected to a channel? | discord.py

Tags: discord.py, voice

I've decided to try making my discord bot play music, but I've gotten stuck already. Mainly due to the fact I can't find any sources to help with the current version, I've been winging everything from the docs. However, I can't figure out how to check if the bot is connected to a voice channel.

I have tried `if not Client.is_connected():`, however that didn't work. If there are any updated sources to help me get the basics of discord.py's voice features, please give me a link :) Here is my code so far:

```py
# ----- ATTEMPT AT VOICE COMMANDS ------
#discord.opus.load_opus() - what goes in bracket???

@client.command(name="join", pass_ctx=True)
async def join(ctx):
    #if not is_connected(): - Client.is_connected() not working

    user = ctx.message.author
    vc = user.voice.channel
    await vc.connect()
    await ctx.send(f"Joined **{vc}**")

    #else:
    #    await ctx.send("I'm already connected!")

@client.command(name="disconnect", pass_ctx=True)
async def disconnect(ctx):
    # if not is_connected(): - once again can't work it out
    vc = ctx.message.guild.voice_client # i don't even know how this worked :D
    await vc.disconnect()

    #else:
    #    await ctx.send("I'm not connected to any channels")

@client.command(name="play", pass_ctx=True)
async def play(ctx, songurl=None):
    if not songurl: # this works at least
        await ctx.send("Please specify a song")
        return
    if not is_connected(): # once again, how to check if bot is connected?
        vc = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if not vc: # i think this should work
            await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")

        await vc.connect()
    # haven't even worked out anything past this point and it's broken
```

ps: sorry for just dumping my whole vc section but i don't understand a lot

Really all that matters here is the play command, but I included the others just because (as you can see from my comments) I don't understand LOTS of what is going on. How should I go about this? Are there any good sources for the current version? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bot can be connected to voice in multiple guilds at the same time, so you need to get the [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient) for the appropriate guild from `Client.voice_clients` and then check [`VoiceClient.is_connected`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.is_connected):

```py
def is_connected(ctx):
    voice_client = get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    return voice_client and voice_client.is_connected()
```

Comment: name VoiceClient is not defined

Comment: My code doesn't reference the `VoiceClient` class directly, does yours?

Comment: I did `if VoiceClient.is_connected():`, after putting this function in, am I missing something?

Comment: Just do `if is_connected(ctx):`.  The `VoiceClient` class is what each individual voice client is an instance of.  You should only be calling the methods of an instance, like I do with `voice_client` above.

Comment: Also, regarding my other question, is there somewhere where I can learn discord.py voice chat? Like a guide? I can't find anything

Comment: You can look at the example voice bot: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py  Looking at that, you can also access the voice client through `ctx.voice_client`

Comment: Where does the `get` function comes from?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get

Answer (score 3):

you could also do

```py
client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    vc = user.voice.channel

    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild) # This allows for more functionality with voice channels

    if voice == None: # None being the default value if the bot isnt in a channel (which is why the is_connected() is returning errors)
        await vc.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"Joined **{vc}**")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I'm already connected!")
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of experimentation with my bot, I found that something similar to this may work for you. It's also pretty quick and easy.

```py
if ctx.guild.voice_client in  bot.voice_clients:
    # Do something here
```

I used this with the `on_message` event, but it could likely work in your use case as well by doing:

```py
if not ctx.guild.voice_client in bot.voice_clients:
    # Do something else here
```